# React-Native: get theme variables from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a file, for example theme.js and inside my theme.js i use constants for my theming.

```
const config = {
 BACKGROUND: 'white'
 ..//
}
export default config;
```

my usage example:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: theme.BACKGROUND }} />
```

Now i may receive some properties from the server, for example button color or something like that. And I want to override the properties in my js file.
Curently whenever I use theme. I use it directly by importing the file.
The problem is once it is imported. We can't change the values.
It would be really helpful if someone can tell me how can i receive `theme` variables efficiently from internet and load them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good solution but a work around would be this :

**You can fetch theme variables in your app.js and save it in redux store or you can save response in asyncStorage**

Comment: I don't want to use redux, then i would need the store in every component. Even my functional components.

Comment: I have used async storage to show currency sign in my app

Comment: and just image if i have 20 constants and i would need to fetch all of them everytime ... that would be really bad practice and less efficient

Comment: It is, I had just one, so I used it proper solution is to use redux store